# Selenium WebDriver - Unable to locate element exception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to take some scores from websites while using webdriver. I tried so far XPath, CSS, Classname but, sometimes it is located the item, sometimes it does not.

This is the HTML code that I have been trying to take it:

```html
<td class="score" rowspan="6"><span class="p1_home">0</span> - <span class="p1_away">0</span></td>
```

And this is my code (that i tried so far) :

```
firstHalf[i] = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"parts\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).Text;
```

Other versions :

```
 firstHalf[i] = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#parts > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.score")).Text;
 firstHalf[i] = Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("score")).Text;
```

And also I tried the child classes (under score classes), but the result is same, sometimes can be located the element, sometimes it cannot.

Any suggestion?

Update : To my code, I put some `wait` or `Thread.Sleep` still will not work.

```
for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string d1 = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='p1_home']")).Text;
                        string d2 = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='p1_away']")).Text;
                        //firstHalf[i] = firstHalf[i].Replace(" ", "");
                        firstHalf[i] = d1 + "-" + d2;
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(300);
                        r -= 1;
                        eventCounter++;
                        if (eventCounter == 10)
                        {
                            errorMsg.sendErrMsg(e);
                            //errorMsg.stopProgram();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Which element u want to locate

Comment: @iamsankalp89 I want to locate class `score` or child classes and these are `p1_home` and `p1_away`

Comment: //span[@class='p1_home'] and //span[@class='p1_away']

Comment: You'd better use ExpectedConditions class instead of sleeping. In that case webdriver will check every 0.5 sec if element is loaded and will fetch it as soon as it appears.

Comment: It seems like the page you are using has some js which modifies the html. How to wait for pages to load this type of content is certainly a point of discussion among automation / test devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution with a different approach. Instead of getting two specific class, I used parent class `score`. Also, I deleted the **"for loop"** and **"try"** and **"catch"** which I am using for finding the object again and again.

To my main loop, I added **"try"** and **"catch"**. When I got the exception, I decreased the loop counter, closed the window and opened again. Also, I added some `Thread.Sleep` in order not to get errors because **Web-Driver** acts so fast this causes a problem.

Updated Version of my Code:

```
for (int i = 0;; i < stopLimit.Count; i++)
{
     try
     {
          Thread.Sleep(500);
          string score = Driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#parts > tbody > 
                                                   tr:nth-child(2) > td.score").Text;
          firstHalf[i] = score.Replace(" ", "");
     }
     catch(Exception)  
     {
          i--;
          Thread.Sleep(1500);
          Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.Last());
          Driver.Close();
          Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.First());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
//span[@class='p1_home']

//span[@class='p1_away']
```

Comment: I am trying write now, and I will test whether the program crash or not

Comment: Ok try and let me know what happens

Comment: Okay, I tried it. On the first run, it worked perfectly, but on the second run, it crashed

Comment: Give some wait and then try

Answer (score 1):

To locate element of particular class and attribute you can use CSS selector. For example:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".score[rowspan='6']")).Text;
```

In case you having trouble to locate element reliably, you might want get it after certain conditions are met, like so:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector(".score[rowspan='6']")));
```

Comment: I am testing other solution. I will let you know whether works or not later

Comment: Added alternative option, to address possible loading time issues.